# Is it possible to bring attributes applied to an object through serialization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have an enum value in our server's solution:

```
public enum TaskStatus
{
    //Description attribute modifies how an Enum's label is displayed when displayed via MVC.
    [Description("Draft")]
    Draft = 1,
    [Description("Being Planned")]
    BeingPlanned = 2,
    [Description("Waiting For Change")]
    WaitingForChange = 3,
    [Description("In Progress")]
    InProgress = 4,
    [Description("Waiting For Customer Information")]
    WaitingCustomerInformation = 5,
    [Description("Cancelled")]
    Cancelled = 6,
    [Description("Completed")]
    Completed = 7
};
```

This enum value gets serialized and passed over to a client as a WCF service reference.

I then display the Enum value in a model. Yet, I note that the Description attribute has been stripped from during the serialization/deserialization process.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.450")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.cormant.com/cswebapi")]
public enum TaskStatus {

    /// <remarks/>
    Draft,

    /// <remarks/>
    BeingPlanned,

    /// <remarks/>
    WaitingForChange,

    /// <remarks/>
    InProgress,

    /// <remarks/>
    WaitingCustomerInformation,

    /// <remarks/>
    Cancelled,

    /// <remarks/>
    Completed,
}
```

I would still like to have the ability to describe how my enum's should be displayed to the end user. Is it possible to do this? Can I re-apply attributes after deserialization?

Comment: Note that it is not serialization that strips the attributes, but rather the code generation that created the code in your second example.

Comment: Oh, I see. Interesting. Hopefully don't have to use a different serialization engine.

Comment: If the user has a reference to the assembly compiled from your first example, they'll get the attributes.  That obviously may not be possible in your case, and there may be some way of getting code gen to keep the attributes, but I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my knowledge is concerned, you cannot transfer you attributes to client through code generation process by inclusion of WCF service reference. There is no way to get the attributes at client end.

While working for one project, i did one trick that was quite effective. I added that Enum file in Client project as a reference file (Add as a Link) as shown below:

[image]

This way you can have your copy of Enum with Description attribute at client-end. If you try to change it, you are actually changing the Server Enum file since it a reference file but the magic is that i will get compiled as part of your client project  at the time of build process. Which is really a great workaround.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: That's a pretty sexy idea. I'll definitely keep it in mind. I'm going to leave this post open for a few hours, but I'll accept this answer by end of day if nothing else comes up. :) Thanks!

Comment: Did you find this answer helpful?

Comment: Sort of! It was a neat idea that I played around with, but I ran into namespacing issues. Since we pass a DTO object through our webservice with the property (e.g. MyDtoObject.Enum) it is of a different namespace than the Enum on the client. I wasn't able to easily assign one to the other, so I backed out and looked around at a few other options, but haven't found a solution as of yet. I accepted for the help, though!